# A mysterious orange bar appeared yesterday at the top of all Stack Exchange sites, partially covering my notifications area at the top-right

Tags: bug

What's up with this new weird super fat orange bar at the top of the screen on all Stack Exchange sites? It partially covers the notifications area at the top-right.

I'm in Google Chrome.

It seems like a mistake they just made on the site.

[image]

Comment: Cannot replicate.

Comment: You have a ton of add-ons. Can you reproduce with all add-ons disabled?

Comment: This looks like the site banner but with no content in it.

Comment: There's always been an orange bar there on SO, but it's normally much smaller than shown in your screenshot. I see it as its normal height of 3px, which is implemented as a `border-top` on elements with the `s-topbar` class. Please check to see if something on your end changes the CSS for the existing element.

Comment: So I turned off all of my browser extensions and the huge orange bar is still there. But, if I open an incognito window and sign in to Stack Overflow, it's not there. I also updated Chrome and restarted the computer. It's still there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed it. It was an extension.

I went to `chrome://extensions/` to manage my extensions. When I click the slider to disable the [**CouponBirds**](https://www.couponbirds.com/) extension, shown below, and then hard-refresh my browser page with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, the orange bar gets thin and normal again.

[image]

Fixed view:

[image]